# auto play features any way to bypass browser default

Tags: javascript, autoplay

So I understand why browsers are trying to stop autoplay, however I am wondering is there anyway to bypass the browsers autoplay detection. Our autoplaying was working fine, until the latest browser update and now a user needs to click on the listen live navigation button before it will allow it to play.

I thought about doing a fake click - but that did not work.

The next option would be to try and figure away to fake user input - but that did not work.

So I am left with asking people to set their browsers permission to autoplay - which you can imagine is not a really good solution.

Funny though they allow video to auto play - I don't understand what the difference is.

Comment: you have video or audio?

Comment: audio. I worked out that I can use the muted javascript function and chrome allows it like 50% of the time. @arminyahya